# Hive UDF with Python

Tags: python, hadoop, pandas, hive

I'm new to python, pandas, and hive and would definitely appreciate some tips.

I have the python code below, which I would like to turn into a UDF in hive.  Only instead of taking a csv as the input, doing the transformations and then exporting another csv, I would like to take a hive table as the input, and then export the results as a new hive table containing the transformed data.

Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')
df = data
df = df.set_index(['Field1','Field2'])
Dummies=pd.get_dummies(df['Field3']).reset_index()
df2=Dummies.drop_duplicates()
df3=df2.groupby(['Field1','Field2']).sum()
df3.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of the `TRANSFORM` function to make use of a UDF written in Python. The detailed steps are outlined [here](http://blog.spryinc.com/2013/09/a-guide-to-user-defined-functions-in.html) and [here](http://andreyfradkin.com/posts/2013/06/15/combining-hive-and-python).

Comment: First link is dead